Checking if a function is convex
I like to find out if  this function convex.
$$f(x)=x_1^2+x_2e^{x_1}-x_1x_2+x_2^2$$
So I checked the definition:
A function $f$ is convex on a convex set $S$ if it satisfies
$f(\alpha x + (1 -\alpha)y) \le \alpha f (x) + (1 -\alpha)f (y)
\forall  0 \le \alpha \le 1$ and for all $x, y \in S$.
Finding $f(\alpha x + (1 -\alpha)y)$ however, what is $f(y)$?
And also, why $f(x)$, when there are two variables ?
Thanks

I would agree that a given function  is a function of two variable $x_1$ and $x_2$. Hence, you have to prove $f(\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_2) \le \alpha f(x_1) + (1-\alpha)f(x_2) \quad \forall (x_1, x_2) \in X \quad \text{and} \quad \forall \alpha \in (0,1)$.

@AntonVrdoljak ok, but what is $f(x_2)$?

The definition cited for convex is using a notation that suggests a function of one argument.  The definition extends in a natural way to functions of two arguments where we think of argument $x$ as being $(x_1,x_2)$, a point in the plane $\mathbb R^2$.  In any case asking about whether a function is convex requires us to state what domain is considered, such as $S$ in the quoted definition.

Sure, but what is $f(y)$?

You can replace $f(x)$ with your definition as $f(x_1,x_2)$, and similarly $f(y)$ becomes a two argument function $f(y_1,y_2)$.  The linear (convex) combination of $x$ and $y$ now becomes the combination of $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$ as points (vectors) in $\mathbb R^2$.

@Superunknown: see the answer given by hardmath.

@hardmath thanks that was very clear. Would you then evaluate the inequality at some point, say (1,1) and see if it holds?

The definition always requires evaluating the inequality at two points.  If you consider the case $x=y$ of equal points, the inequality trivially becomes an equality.

In the problem posed, I would assume your domain is $S = \mathbb R^2$.  So when one writes $f(x)$ as a function of one argument, but expresses it as:
$$ x_1^2 + x_1 e^{x_2} - x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 $$
the notation is being slightly abused.
Treat the linear combination $\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y$ as a vector combination:
$$ \alpha (x_1,x_2) + (1-\alpha) (y_1,y_2) $$
and the expressions will all be defined to compare $f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y)$ with:
$$ \alpha f(x_1,x_2) + (1-\alpha) f(y_1,y_2) $$

A common check for whether a smooth function of more than one variable is convex is to examine whether the Hessian of the function (matrix of second partial derivatives) is positive semi-definite.
Since $ f(x) = x_1^2 +x_1 e^{x_2} - x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 $, the Hessian is this $2\times 2$ matrix:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1+e^{x_2} \\ 1+e^{x_2} & 2x_1 e^{x_2} \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
But this last is not positive definite (or semi-definite) everywhere in the entire plane $\mathbb R^2$.  For example on the axis $x_1 = 0$ the Hessian's determinant is $-(1+e^{x_2})^2$. The determinant will be negative there, hence the Hessian has a negative eigenvalue and is not positive definite.

Can one evaluate the final inequality at some random point, say (1,1)? Or must it be  at a minimum?

Just using one point will not tell us anything about convexity, as the case $x=y$ holds trivially (with equality) for any function.  Also if $x,y$ are distinct points, then the convex combination of them is yet a third point where the function is evaluated (one that is strictly between $x$ and $y$).

How does one find the answer to the inequality then?

You might want to do a simplified problem, say $x_1^2 - x_1 x_2 + x_2^2$, to get a sense of how to verify the inequality holds (hence convexity of the function).
